# dataframe to shift python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time

i Have a df with time. what i want to do is create another column and set it as Shift.
Everyday 7AM to 7PM is Day Shift and 7PM to 7AM is night Shift.

ex: 2/11: If time btw 2/11 7 AM to 2/11 7 PM is 2-11 Day and **2/11 7 PM to 2/12 7 AM   is 2/11 Night.**

To create 'Day-Shift' column first I created 'Date' and then created 'Date-Shift' column.

But the problem is my code correctly classifies Each day 'Day' shift (7AM to 7PM) but it fails to classify 'night' shift correctly. Please check highlighted rows.

Ex: 21st row: its Day-Shift value should be '01-07 Night' instead of '01-08 Night'

[image]

mycode:

```
df2["Date"]=df2['Time'].astype(str).str[:10]
df2["Shift"] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Time'],unit='s').apply(lambda x: "Day" if x.hour >= 7 and x.hour <= 18 else "Night")
df2['Date']=df2['Date'].astype(str)
df2['Date'] = df2['Date'].str[5:]
df2["Day-Shift"]=df2["Date"]+" "+df2["Shift"]
df2.head(2)
```

sample df:

```
{'Time': {17: Timestamp('2021-01-07 23:11:53'),
  18: Timestamp('2021-01-07 23:11:53'),
  19: Timestamp('2021-01-07 23:29:13'),
  20: Timestamp('2021-01-07 23:29:13'),
  21: Timestamp('2021-01-08 00:12:23'),
  22: Timestamp('2021-01-08 00:12:23'),
  23: Timestamp('2021-01-08 00:19:43'),
  24: Timestamp('2021-01-08 00:19:43'),
  25: Timestamp('2021-01-08 00:58:13'),
  26: Timestamp('2021-01-08 00:58:13'),
  27: Timestamp('2021-01-08 01:24:13'),
  28: Timestamp('2021-01-08 01:24:13'),
  29: Timestamp('2021-01-08 06:31:09'),
  30: Timestamp('2021-01-08 06:31:09'),
  31: Timestamp('2021-01-08 06:54:39'),
  32: Timestamp('2021-01-08 06:54:39'),
  33: Timestamp('2021-01-08 06:54:49'),
  34: Timestamp('2021-01-08 07:00:00'),
  35: Timestamp('2021-01-08 07:16:29'),
  36: Timestamp('2021-01-08 07:17:59'),
  37: Timestamp('2021-01-08 07:17:59'),
  38: Timestamp('2021-01-08 07:28:39'),
  39: Timestamp('2021-01-08 07:28:39'),
  40: Timestamp('2021-01-08 07:48:59'),
  41: Timestamp('2021-01-08 07:48:59'),
  42: Timestamp('2021-01-08 10:04:59'),
  43: Timestamp('2021-01-08 10:07:59'),
  44: Timestamp('2021-01-08 12:19:49'),
  45: Timestamp('2021-01-08 12:19:49'),
  46: Timestamp('2021-01-08 12:24:09'),
  47: Timestamp('2021-01-08 12:24:09'),
  48: Timestamp('2021-01-08 18:19:05'),
  49: Timestamp('2021-01-08 18:19:05')},
 'Date': {17: '01-07',
  18: '01-07',
  19: '01-07',
  20: '01-07',
  21: '01-08',
  22: '01-08',
  23: '01-08',
  24: '01-08',
  25: '01-08',
  26: '01-08',
  27: '01-08',
  28: '01-08',
  29: '01-08',
  30: '01-08',
  31: '01-08',
  32: '01-08',
  33: '01-08',
  34: '01-08',
  35: '01-08',
  36: '01-08',
  37: '01-08',
  38: '01-08',
  39: '01-08',
  40: '01-08',
  41: '01-08',
  42: '01-08',
  43: '01-08',
  44: '01-08',
  45: '01-08',
  46: '01-08',
  47: '01-08',
  48: '01-08',
  49: '01-08'},
 'Shift': {17: 'Night',
  18: 'Night',
  19: 'Night',
  20: 'Night',
  21: 'Night',
  22: 'Night',
  23: 'Night',
  24: 'Night',
  25: 'Night',
  26: 'Night',
  27: 'Night',
  28: 'Night',
  29: 'Night',
  30: 'Night',
  31: 'Night',
  32: 'Night',
  33: 'Night',
  34: 'Day',
  35: 'Day',
  36: 'Day',
  37: 'Day',
  38: 'Day',
  39: 'Day',
  40: 'Day',
  41: 'Day',
  42: 'Day',
  43: 'Day',
  44: 'Day',
  45: 'Day',
  46: 'Day',
  47: 'Day',
  48: 'Day',
  49: 'Day'},
 'Day-Shift': {17: '01-07 Night',
  18: '01-07 Night',
  19: '01-07 Night',
  20: '01-07 Night',
  21: '01-08 Night',
  22: '01-08 Night',
  23: '01-08 Night',
  24: '01-08 Night',
  25: '01-08 Night',
  26: '01-08 Night',
  27: '01-08 Night',
  28: '01-08 Night',
  29: '01-08 Night',
  30: '01-08 Night',
  31: '01-08 Night',
  32: '01-08 Night',
  33: '01-08 Night',
  34: '01-08 Day',
  35: '01-08 Day',
  36: '01-08 Day',
  37: '01-08 Day',
  38: '01-08 Day',
  39: '01-08 Day',
  40: '01-08 Day',
  41: '01-08 Day',
  42: '01-08 Day',
  43: '01-08 Day',
  44: '01-08 Day',
  45: '01-08 Day',
  46: '01-08 Day',
  47: '01-08 Day',
  48: '01-08 Day',
  49: '01-08 Day'}}
```

Comment: To increase the possibility of getting an answer please provide data frame as text not image

Comment: i provided dataframe as a dictionary. 1st image is just to the identification of my problem. Please check the end of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subtract one day from `Time` if hour is less like `7` in [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html), then create `Shift` by compare hours in [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) and set values by [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and last join columns with [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for extract days and months:

```
df['Date'] = (df['Time'].mask(df['Time'].dt.hour.lt(7), 
                              df['Time'] - pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=1)))

df["Shift"] = np.where(df['Time'].dt.hour.between(7, 18), 'Day','Night')

df["Day-Shift"] = df["Date"].dt.strftime('%m-%d') + " " + df["Shift"]
```

---

```
print (df)
                  Time                Date  Shift    Day-Shift
17 2021-01-07 23:11:53 2021-01-07 23:11:53  Night  01-07 Night
18 2021-01-07 23:11:53 2021-01-07 23:11:53  Night  01-07 Night
19 2021-01-07 23:29:13 2021-01-07 23:29:13  Night  01-07 Night
20 2021-01-07 23:29:13 2021-01-07 23:29:13  Night  01-07 Night
21 2021-01-08 00:12:23 2021-01-07 00:12:23  Night  01-07 Night
22 2021-01-08 00:12:23 2021-01-07 00:12:23  Night  01-07 Night
23 2021-01-08 00:19:43 2021-01-07 00:19:43  Night  01-07 Night
24 2021-01-08 00:19:43 2021-01-07 00:19:43  Night  01-07 Night
25 2021-01-08 00:58:13 2021-01-07 00:58:13  Night  01-07 Night
26 2021-01-08 00:58:13 2021-01-07 00:58:13  Night  01-07 Night
27 2021-01-08 01:24:13 2021-01-07 01:24:13  Night  01-07 Night
28 2021-01-08 01:24:13 2021-01-07 01:24:13  Night  01-07 Night
29 2021-01-08 06:31:09 2021-01-07 06:31:09  Night  01-07 Night
30 2021-01-08 06:31:09 2021-01-07 06:31:09  Night  01-07 Night
31 2021-01-08 06:54:39 2021-01-07 06:54:39  Night  01-07 Night
32 2021-01-08 06:54:39 2021-01-07 06:54:39  Night  01-07 Night
33 2021-01-08 06:54:49 2021-01-07 06:54:49  Night  01-07 Night
34 2021-01-08 07:00:00 2021-01-08 07:00:00    Day    01-08 Day
35 2021-01-08 07:16:29 2021-01-08 07:16:29    Day    01-08 Day
36 2021-01-08 07:17:59 2021-01-08 07:17:59    Day    01-08 Day
37 2021-01-08 07:17:59 2021-01-08 07:17:59    Day    01-08 Day
38 2021-01-08 07:28:39 2021-01-08 07:28:39    Day    01-08 Day
39 2021-01-08 07:28:39 2021-01-08 07:28:39    Day    01-08 Day
40 2021-01-08 07:48:59 2021-01-08 07:48:59    Day    01-08 Day
41 2021-01-08 07:48:59 2021-01-08 07:48:59    Day    01-08 Day
42 2021-01-08 10:04:59 2021-01-08 10:04:59    Day    01-08 Day
43 2021-01-08 10:07:59 2021-01-08 10:07:59    Day    01-08 Day
44 2021-01-08 12:19:49 2021-01-08 12:19:49    Day    01-08 Day
45 2021-01-08 12:19:49 2021-01-08 12:19:49    Day    01-08 Day
46 2021-01-08 12:24:09 2021-01-08 12:24:09    Day    01-08 Day
47 2021-01-08 12:24:09 2021-01-08 12:24:09    Day    01-08 Day
48 2021-01-08 18:19:05 2021-01-08 18:19:05    Day    01-08 Day
49 2021-01-08 18:19:05 2021-01-08 18:19:05    Day    01-08 Day
```

Comment: Can you please check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66778193/add-new-rows-to-dataframe-based-on-condition-python-pandas